# How to retrieve User Management Report?

Tags: smartsheet-api

I have been using Python to explore smartsheet api in order to retrieve information for Power BI and/or user management.

Some of the reports I will like to retrieve are the ones from Account Administration tab. For example the report from "Download User List (csv)" or "Download Sheet Access Report (csv)".

Is there a report id for these, or a direct link?

Answer (score 1):

The [API documentation](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#list-reports) has all the details and code examples you may need.

First, list the reports the user has access to, to find the name of the report you're looking for.

```
response = ss_client.Reports.list_reports(include_all=True)
reports = response.data
```

Then once you've identified the corresponding report, use the report's `id` to then request a csv export.

```
ss_client.Reports.get_report_as_csv(
  3882962191181700,       # report_id
  download_folder_path
)
```